# how to perform logout in actionbar

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need help. I have actionbar in my app. And I want my logout inside of it. How can I do that? I have already these things. But I don't have that session.java. I have attempt to copy others' code but it showed some errors. Please help me. Thanks guys!

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            logout();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  private void logout() {
        session.logout();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
  }
```

Comment: where is session method?

Comment: hmmmm. I have no idea also with the session method. Can you help me?sorry i'm new to this things.

Comment: Please add complete class code.

Comment: Hello prashant ca i reach you on fb?

Comment: Sure @Joselito..

Comment: what's your name on facebook and your email?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use shared preference to keep the session and i think `session.logout();`this method created in a class where they keep the session using shared preference. ok right now i will tell you how can you keep your login session and how to logout.

step one : when you are trying to login and you got the success response through JSON Api or from your sqlite database just use shared preference and set positive flag value there.

setp two : and then when you click logout button from toolbar in `onOptionsItemSelected` method just change that shared preference's value to negative.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);startActivity(intent);
finish();

yes with this way you will keep your session. and after clicking logout you will make the shared preference value false.

Comment: should i delete the code that i have inserted? and just use tthis code " 
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);startActivity(intent); finish();" em confused @.@. Sorry i'm in the process of learning hehe. Hope you'll udnerstand sir :D.

Comment: after startActivity(intent); then you have to finish the activity. don't delete full code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Like this sir?



public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

        public static final String my_shared_preferences = "my_shared_preferences";
        public static final String session_status = "session_status";
        Boolean session = false;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


            final TextView mShowDialog =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShowDialog);
            final TextView tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);

            //Check session login if TRUE then go directly MainActivity
            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);


            if (session) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }



            tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
                }
            });
            mShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_login,null);
                     final EditText hehe=  mView.findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
                    final EditText hehe1=  mView.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
                    final Button bLogin =  mView.findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);

                   bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            final String Username = hehe.getText().toString();
                             final String Password = hehe1.getText().toString();

                            // Response received from the server
                            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                                        if (success) {

                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                            editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                        } else {
                                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                                    .create()
                                                    .show();
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(Username, Password, responseListener);
                            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                            queue.add(loginRequest);
                        }
                    });
                    mbuilder.setView(mView);
                    AlertDialog dialog = mbuilder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }
            });


        }
    }
```